# SQL queries that compare values of multiple rows and columns

Tags: sql

I've got a table `RESULTS` that contains 8 separate number columns which can be in the range of [1,47] and `date_id` that is fk to date table.

What I would like is to find what the highest value across all rows and number attributes is (that I managed to do), and then to find the latest date when that value appeared (there are no duplicate dates).

Second problem seems pretty brutal to me.

The table is the same as first one (RESULTS) but I need to find the rows with highest occurrence of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

So if one row has the values of `1 ,35, 5, 7, 43, 22, 3` and second one `32, 2, 3, 21, 25, 40, 1` I need it to return to me the first row since it contains 3 values in the range of [`1,5`].

EDIT: sorry, I'm a little tired. well spotted errors.
Here is the sample of the RESULTS (first 2 columns are id and `date_id`)

[results table](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7nl4k3mkihhzm2g/AADp8Bum4urgJEO01tH8gM5da)

First query should return either date of the row 7 or 8 based on which date is later, since both rows contain value 46 since that is a highest value in a table.

Second query should return row 10 which has 3 values in [`1,5`] range (`4,5,3`). If there were multiple rows with 3 values in that range, it should return them all. 
Hope that clears it up.

Comment: Can you give us more detail?  Maybe the table schema, example data, and desired output along with what you have tried so far.

Comment: For the second problem, only one row from the entire table needs to be returned? What if more than row has equally highest number of numbers 1-5?

Comment: In your example data for the second problem, the second row also contain 3 numbers in the 1-5 range: 2, 3, 1. Also, you state that there should be eight number columns, and yet your sample only has seven, and no date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify which RDBMS so I will assume SQL Server:

```
select top 1
    date_id
from (
    select 
        date_id,
        ( case when Col1 between 1 and 5 then 1 else 0 end
        + case when Col2 between 1 and 5 then 1 else 0 end
        + case when Col3 between 1 and 5 then 1 else 0 end
        + case when Col4 between 1 and 5 then 1 else 0 end
        + case when Col5 between 1 and 5 then 1 else 0 end
        ) as Value
    from RESULTS
) d
order by Value desc
```

Comment: it's Oracle, but that helped immensely! Thank you. Do you have any suggestion for the first one?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for the first one using Oracle function GREATEST.

```
select * 
from ( select greatest(result.no1, result.no2, result.no3, result.no4, result.no5, result.no6, result.no7,result.no8)    
            , date.date 
     from result 
     join date 
     on date.id=result.date_id
     order by 1 desc, 2 desc
   )
where rownum=1;
```